# Getting notifications with accessibilty service if device is muted?

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

The Problem is:
My accessibility service doesn't get called on a new notification, if the device is muted (I guess on Android 5+). I found nothing on the Internet. Is there any way to enable accessibility service for muted devices?

I need this for my app "AutoResponder for WhatsApp" to get notifications no matter which phone state.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting tidbit you've found here. I feel this is not intended behavior, but none the less I think the best solution would be to use [NotificationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) and [setInterruptionFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#setInterruptionFilter(int)) to [INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL).

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

mNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL);
```

This will disable DnD mode and your AccessibilityService should start receiving events again without restarting the app or anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't help, cause this was added in API 23 and I need it at least in API 21. Isn't there any other solution?